# Correct deleting of a (virtual) device in windows drivers

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I'm writing a WDM driver. It doesn't operate any physical device, it's a sort of a filter driver. I'd like to skip all the irrelevant details. To be short, the problem is this:

Right now I create a single device object + symbolic link (`IoCreateDevice` + `IoCreateSymbolicLink`) within my `DriverEntry` routine, to communicate with the user-mode component.

My goal is to be able to create and delete device objects when needed. So that multiple user-mode components may communicate with the driver, whereas for each of them I'll have a separate context (associated with this device object). I thought about just creating and deleting device objects (via `IoDeleteDevice`) when needed. But I smell a race condition here.

How the hell is this synchronized with my dispatch routine? I mean, when deleting the device I can actually be processing an IRP for it (initiated by user-mode).

I've found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463218.aspx) describing (at least what I understood to be) this exact situation.

Is this the intended way to solve this?

**EDIT**: So far the mentioned article won't solve my problem. It says that my driver should call `IoAcquireRemoveLock` whenever it start an I/O. My problem however is different. The I/O is started on behalf of the user-mode -> I/O manager. So that I don't about this until I reach the dispatch routine.

I'll rephrase the question in a different manner: does `IoDeleteDevice` delete the device + extension immediately? Or it checks if the device is still in use? If so - should I perform the cleanup of the extension before calling `IoDeleteDevice`, or after, or I should just wait for `IRP_MJ_whatever` meaning that the device reference count is finally zero?

Thanks in advance.